# How to find itteration count

Tags: websphere, ibm-integration-bus

I am using timer notification node in my IIB message flow. How do I find the irritation count and declare a variable which should auto increment for every message flow?

Comment: I mean increase the value for every itteration count

Comment: Would you be able to further expand your question. Is your requirement that on each trigger of the timer node you want a counter to be incremented. How are you planning to use this counter value ?